# List.clear() followed by List.add() not working

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have the following C# Class/Function:

```
    class Hand
    {

    private List<Card> myCards = new List<Card>();

    public void sortBySuitValue()
    {
        IEnumerable<Card> query = from s in myCards
                                  orderby (int)s.suit, (int)s.value
                                  select s;

        myCards = new List<Card>();
        myCards.AddRange(query);
    }
 }
```

On a card Game. This works fine, however, I had trouble at first, instead of using myCards = new List(); to 'reset' myCards, I would use myCards.clear(), however, once I called the clear function, I would not be able to call myCards.add() or myCards.addRange(). The count would stay at zero. Is my current approach good? Is using LINQ to sort my cards good/bad?

Comment: Can you post the code that wasn't working?

Comment: Why do you initialize the myCards again in method?

Comment: @Rosarch, he would create a query against `myCards` but then clear the list. Since the query is lazily-evaluated, the query would be evaluated against the empty list when he tried to use `AddRange`. Think `write query against list -> clear list -> evaluate query of list`.

Comment: I can't see any problem in this, just you can reduce your code, but there is no problem with this.

Comment: why didn't you accept the good answer?

Answer (score 4):

this would work

```
    class Hand
    {

    private List<Card> myCards = new List<Card>();

    public void sortBySuitValue()
    {
        myCards = (from s in myCards
                                  orderby (int)s.suit, (int)s.value
                                  select s).ToList();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that an `IEnumerable` is a query, not a list. Since it's selecting from `myCards`, if you clear `myCards` before actually executing the query, it'll return no results. You can run the query before clearing the list by using `IEnumerable.ToList()` thus:

```
public void sortBySuitValue()
{
    var query = (from s in myCards
                              orderby (int)s.suit, (int)s.value
                              select s).ToList();

    myCards.Clear();
    myCards.AddRange(query);
}
```

Comment: Of course, since you actually have a List<Card> at this point, you may as well just use it as is, but hopefully the above illustrates why you get the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need LINQ to sort, the List class already provides a Sort method which you can pass a `Comparison` delegate suitable for you. 
Example for sorting strings by length:

```
        List<string> myList = new List<string>( new string[] { "foo", "bar" } );

        myList.Sort((x, y) => 
        {
            if (x.Length == y.Length)
                return 0;
            else if (x.Length < y.Length)
                return 1;
            else return -1; 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use LINQ to generate a query to create a new list (or repopulate a cleared list), but I'd rather use the `Sort` instance method of `List<T>` to go ahead and sort my existing list in place in this particular situation.

```
List<Card> myCards = SomeMethodGeneratingCards();

Comparison<Card> cardComparison = (card1, card2) =>
    {
        int value = card1.Suit.CompareTo(card2.Suit);
        if (value == 0)
            value = card1.Value.CompareTo(card2.Value);

        return value;
    };

myCards.Sort(cardComparison);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the data inplace in the list:

```
myCards.Sort( (l,r) => 
     l.suit.Equals(r.suit) ? l.value.CompareTo(r.value) : l.suit.CompareTo(r.suit));
```

This way you won't have to create a new list which is assigned to your old variable.

Answer (score 0):

To `myCards` is filled with information that you get with the sentence LINQ need to Call some method such as `.ToList()` If you do not myCards will contain nothing.

This should work:

```
    class Hand
    {

    private List<Card> myCards = new List<Card>();

    public void sortBySuitValue()
    {
        myCards = (from s in myCards
                                  orderby (int)s.suit, (int)s.value
                                  select s).ToList();
    }
```